# Bandwidth measuring with Boomerang -> wait for the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, boomerang

I have a javascript (jQuery) method (function) which gets me the bandwidth vie Boomerang.

The function looks this:

```
this.getBandwidth = function() {
    var cookie = BOOMR.utils.getCookie('BA');
    if (cookie !== null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Now it takes a while to get the Cookie and cookie being no longer null. So if cookie is actually still null, I need to start over. If I just call getBandwidth() in the else part again I get a stack overflow. Already tried to use while loop for checking 'cookie' but it blocks the browser.

How can I simply repeat the assignment until cookie is ready? Pulling my hair out!

Thanks.

Comment: So `BOOMR.utils.getCookie('BA')` is async or what?

Comment: How is the `BA` cookie being set? One option is to use a `setTimeout` to keep checking for the cookie, but I assume there's an async function elsewhere that sets the cookie. Adding a callback or promise to that function would probably be ideal. As a side note, a function called `getBandwidth` that returns a bool is confusing.

Comment: @JasonP: Thought that too. But I tried all day to do it right. I never got it to work. And yes, I know about the bool. This is only for posting it here ;-)

Comment: @programisto callbacks or promises are the way to react to completion of async tasks. If you're having trouble getting it to work, add more context to your question, or create a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem and we'll see if we can figure out where things are going wrong.

Comment: created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/k5FKJ/

Comment: Now I have this split up in two functions but it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to the before_beacon event of the BOOMR object.  See docs here:
http://lognormal.github.io/boomerang/doc/api/BOOMR.html

```
BOOMR.subscribe("before_beacon", getBandwidth, null, this);
```

Put that somewhere after you define your `getBandwidth` function, and it will be called once boomerang has finished doing everything it needs to do.